# Cannot import directory path to qmlscene

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, qml

I am trying to import directory in QML as explained, here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-syntax-directoryimports.html. I have the following

ubuntu-app

| - extras1

| - extras2

| - myapp

       | - app1.qml

       | - app2.qml

hence, in app1.qml I wrote

```
import "../extras1"
import "../extras2"
```

And when I runt it with qmlscene, I got the following error

```
"../extras1": no such directory
```

Comment: "../" is ambiguous , use the full path

Comment: You are importing directories the correct way. QMLSCENE shouldn't give you that error. It would help if you could push your code to a public place so that I can take a look at it.